# Get cell data 'datatable 1.10.6'

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to get cell data on click, I got this code, but it give me `undefined`.
Can anybody help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = $('#performanceReportLocation').DataTable();        
    $('#performanceReportLocation`tbody').on('click',"td",function() {
         alert( table.cell( this ).data() );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: "#performanceReportLocation`tbody" is an illegal selector.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the syntax is this way :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    var cell = table.cell( this );
    var data = cell.data();
});
```

Comment: wow interesting, here is the working jsfiddle with above code http://jsfiddle.net/pj6zddkn/

Comment: yes i checked it out, but its not working on my code.

Comment: Works perfectly well. This one of several correct ways to do it. Here is a exsplicit 1.10.6 version -> http://jsfiddle.net/pj6zddkn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but there is just one typo. *'#performanceReportLocation`tbody'* contains a *`* instead of a space.